# Como verifico se um $_FILE foi definido?

Tags: php, imagem, upload, sistema-de-arquivos

tudo certo?

Estou tentando executar essa código:

```
if(empty($_FILES['imagem']['name'])){
    $upload = new Upload();
    $novoNome = $upload->efetuarUpload($_FILES["imagem"]);
    $pontoTrocaAlterado->setImagem($novoNome);
}
```

Eu preciso que apenas quando o usuário fizer upload do arquivo, ele executar a função efetuar Upload e setar o novo nome da imagem. No entanto fazendo os testes, mesmo quando o usuário não faz upload do arquivo, o nome é alterado.

Já usei diversas funções como:

in_array
array_key_exists

Mas não tive sucesso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O nome de qual arquivo é alterado quando não é feito o upload?

Comment: Campo imagem, no banco de dados

Comment: isset() não resolve o seu caso?

Comment: Aliás, não faltou um `!` antes do `empty`, para entrar no `if` somente quando o valor não é vazio?

Comment: Consegui resolver, como era um caso de alteração do arquivo eu fiz o seguinte:

 `if(!empty($_FILES['imagem']['name'])){
        $upload = new Upload();
        $novoNome = $upload->efetuarUpload($_FILES["imagem"]);
        $pontoTrocaAlterado->setImagem($novoNome);
    }else{
        $pontoTrocaAlterado->setImagem($imagem);
    }`.

@AndersonCarlosWoss eu segui sua sugestão de acrescentar **!** , mas observei q mesmo eu não definindo o nome ele não gravava no banco, pois o banco não aceita nulo, então gravei o nome antigo do arquivo.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver, como era um caso de alteração do arquivo eu fiz o seguinte:

```
    if(!empty($_FILES['imagem']['name'])){
    $upload = new Upload();
    $novoNome = $upload->efetuarUpload($_FILES["imagem"]);
    $bannerAlterado->setImagem($novoNome);
}else{
    $bannerAlterado->setImagem($imagem);
}
```

eu segui a sugestão do @AndersonCarlosWoss de acrescentar **!** , mas observei q mesmo eu não definindo o nome ele não gravava no banco, pois o banco não aceita nulo, então gravei o nome antigo do arquivo.